# MySQL WHERE EXISTS not working

Tags: mysql, subquery, exists

I am using Doctrine with Zend Framework 2 to do a query on my invoices table using a sub-query.

Here's the simplified generated SQL with parameters filled in

```
SELECT *

FROM invoices i1 

WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM invoices i2 WHERE i2.invoice_first_name IN ('stephen') OR i2.invoice_middle_name IN ('stephen') OR i2.invoice_surname IN('stephen')))

ORDER BY i1.invoice_id DESC
```

The problem I am having is that when I run this query in phpMyAdmin it returns all the invoices, even those that do not contain the name 'stephen'.

However when I run the sub-query separately it returns 2 rows which is correct.

```
SELECT * FROM invoices i2 WHERE i2.invoice_first_name IN ('stephen') OR i2.invoice_middle_name IN ('stephen') OR i2.invoice_surname IN('stephen')
```

So why doesn't the sub-query work with `EXISTS`, what am I missing?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE

Since your subquery returns some row(s), the where clause is true -  for *every* row in the invoice table.